# cube with different images openGL android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am displaying images using openGL library. How to Display Different images on each face of cube in openGL ?

This is my mainactivity class.

```
package com.nea.nehe.lesson06;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * The initial Android Activity, setting and initiating
 * the OpenGL ES Renderer Class @see Lesson06.java
 * 
 * @author Savas Ziplies (nea/INsanityDesign)
 */
public class Run extends Activity {

    /** The OpenGL View */
    private GLSurfaceView glSurface;

    /**
     * Initiate the OpenGL View and set our own
     * Renderer (@see Lesson06.java)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Create an Instance with this Activity
        glSurface = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        //Set our own Renderer and hand the renderer this Activity Context
        glSurface.setRenderer(new Lesson06(this));
        //Set the GLSurface as View to this Activity
        setContentView(glSurface);
    }

    /**
     * Remember to resume the glSurface
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        glSurface.onResume();
    }

    /**
     * Also pause the glSurface
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        glSurface.onPause();
    }

}
```

This my Renderer class.

```
public class Lesson06 implements Renderer {

    /** Cube instance */
    private Cube cube;  

    /* Rotation values for all axis */
    private float xrot;             //X Rotation ( NEW )
    private float yrot;             //Y Rotation ( NEW )
    private float zrot;             //Z Rotation ( NEW )

    /** The Activity Context ( NEW ) */
    private Context context;

    /**
     * Instance the Cube object and set 
     * the Activity Context handed over
     */
    public Lesson06(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        cube = new Cube();
    }

    /**
     * The Surface is created/init()
     */
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {       
        //Load the texture for the cube once during Surface creation
        cube.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            //Enable Texture Mapping ( NEW )
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            //Enable Smooth Shading
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);    //Black Background
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     //Depth Buffer Setup
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            //Enables Depth Testing
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);             //The Type Of Depth Testing To Do

        //Really Nice Perspective Calculations
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST); 
    }

    /**
     * Here we do our drawing
     */
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        //Clear Screen And Depth Buffer
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);    
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Current Modelview Matrix

        gl.glActiveTexture(gl.GL_TEXTURE0);


        //Drawing
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);     //Move 5 units into the screen
        gl.glScalef(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);          //Scale the Cube to 80 percent, otherwise it would be too large for the screen

        //Rotate around the axis based on the rotation matrix (rotation, x, y, z)
        gl.glRotatef(xrot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   //X
        gl.glRotatef(yrot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   //Y
        gl.glRotatef(zrot, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   //Z

        cube.draw(gl);                          //Draw the Cube 

        //Change rotation factors (nice rotation)
        xrot += 0.3f;
        yrot += 0.2f;
        zrot += 0.4f;
    }

    /**
     * If the surface changes, reset the view
     */
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if(height == 0) {                       //Prevent A Divide By Zero By
            height = 1;                         //Making Height Equal One
        }

        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     //Reset The Current Viewport
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select The Projection Matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Projection Matrix

        //Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Modelview Matrix
    }
}
```

And finally this is my cube class for drawing cube.

```
package com.nea.nehe.lesson06;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;

/**
 * This class is an object representation of 
 * a Cube containing the vertex information,
 * texture coordinates, the vertex indices
 * and drawing functionality, which is called 
 * by the renderer.
 * 
 * @author Savas Ziplies (nea/INsanityDesign)
 */
public class Cube {

    /** The buffer holding the vertices */
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    /** The buffer holding the texture coordinates */
    private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
    /** The buffer holding the indices */
    private ByteBuffer indexBuffer;

    /** Our texture pointer */
    private int[] textures = new int[1];

    /** 
     * The initial vertex definition
     * 
     * Note that each face is defined, even
     * if indices are available, because
     * of the texturing we want to achieve 
     */ 
    private float vertices[] = {
                        //Vertices according to faces
                        -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, //Vertex 0
                        1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //v1
                        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  //v2
                        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   //v3

                        1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //...
                        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,         
                        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,

                        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
                        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,            
                        1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
                        -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,

                        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
                        -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,         
                        -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
                        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

                        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
                        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,         
                        -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,

                        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,           
                        -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
                                            };

    /** The initial texture coordinates (u, v) */   
    private float texture[] = {         
                        //Mapping coordinates for the vertices
                        0.0f, 0.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f, 

                        0.0f, 0.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f,

                        0.0f, 0.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f,

                        0.0f, 0.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f,

                        0.0f, 0.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f,

                        0.0f, 0.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f,

                                            };

    /** The initial indices definition */   
    private byte indices[] = {
                        //Faces definition
                        0,1,3, 0,3,2,           //Face front
                        4,5,7, 4,7,6,           //Face right
                        8,9,11, 8,11,10,        //... 
                        12,13,15, 12,15,14,     
                        16,17,19, 16,19,18,     
                        20,21,23, 20,23,22,     
                                            };

    /**
     * The Cube constructor.
     * 
     * Initiate the buffers.
     */
    public Cube() {
        //
        ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        //
        byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        textureBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(texture);
        textureBuffer.position(0);

        //
        indexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length);
        indexBuffer.put(indices);
        indexBuffer.position(0);
    }

    /**
     * The object own drawing function.
     * Called from the renderer to redraw this instance
     * with possible changes in values.
     * 
     * @param gl - The GL Context
     */
    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        //Bind our only previously generated texture in this case
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        //Point to our buffers
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        //Set the face rotation
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);

        //Enable the vertex and texture state
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

        //Draw the vertices as triangles, based on the Index Buffer information
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexBuffer);

        //Disable the client state before leaving
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }

    /**
     * Load the textures
     * 
     * @param gl - The GL Context
     * @param context - The Activity context
     */
    public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
        //Get the texture from the Android resource directory
        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.nehe);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            //BitmapFactory is an Android graphics utility for images
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        } finally {
            //Always clear and close
            try {
                is.close();
                is = null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        //Generate one texture pointer...
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        //...and bind it to our array
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        //Create Nearest Filtered Texture
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        //Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);

        //Use the Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        //Clean up
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you really want to use the deprecated functionalities... Well, then render each face of the cube, each time your render a new face bind another texture... OR use the *Shader Programmable Pipeline* and start using Shaders!

Comment: Probably he is trying to be backward comaptible...But well,I would assume most of mobile hardware today already supports ES2.0